# Как программно отправить на почту письмо?

Tags: java, android, email

Как программно отправить на почту письмо?
Без программ-посредников вроде `Gmail`. Что бы приложение выполняло функции почтового клиента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть стандартный инструментарий [JavaMail](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaMail). Примеров куча, например, [вот](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Answer (score 0):

почтовый клиент отправляет почту через почтовый сервер. Он может быть как локальным, так и внешним, вроде gmail. Ключевое словоcочетание соединение по smtp

Comment: Ну я понял что через smtp), просто может либа есть какая то которая по средствам ее можно отправить обычно письмо, со словом Hello, на указанную почту?

Comment: все равно во всех библиотеках нужно указывать smtp сервер. А для внешних имя и пароль, кроме того. И библиотека это слишком широко. Для чего Perl, PHP, С/С++?

Comment: Ну вот допустим либа есть отличная https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground

Но она начинается от 15 SDK, а мне от 11 нужно